# Edit large textfile in mac terminal

Tags: regex, macos, terminal

I have this very large dictionary file with 1 word on each line, and I would like to trim it down.

What I would like to do is leave 3-6 letter improper nouns, so it has to detect the words based on these:

1. if the word is less than 3 letters, delete it
2. if the word is more than 6 letters, delete it
3. if the word has a capital letter, delete it
4. if the word has a single quote or space, delete it.

I used this:

```
cat Downloads/en-US/en-US.dic | egrep '[a-z]{3,6}' > Downloads/3-6.txt
```

but the output is incorrect. It outputs the words with greater than 3 characters alright, but that's about my progress so far.

So how do I go about doing this in the mac terminal? There must be a way to do this right?

Comment: "If the word has a space"? Words don't have spaces, by definition.

Comment: @You Debatable - see 'car door' (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/car+door) for example. :)

Comment: @Telemachus: I'd say that's two words.

Comment: @You And I wouldn't fight much either way you describe it, but some dictionaries include entries for multi-word items was my more serious point.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will select only words that consist of exactly three to six lowercase a-z letters:

```
egrep '^[a-z]{3,6}$' /usr/share/dict/words > filtered.txt
```

Replace `/usr/share/dict/words` with your input file, and `filtered.txt` with a name for your output file. I just verified that this works on my Mac. Hope this helps!

Comment: To pick up on this: a sequence like `{3,6}` often confuses people. It *does not* do what many of us initially think. It won't fail if the regex matches **7** characters in the a-z set. (Think of it this way: a seven-letter word like 'limited' *does* match the description "has a sequence of between 3 and 6 characters in the a-z set". If that's **all** the regex asks for, the match is made when the 'e' is reached.) To make the regex rule out words of 7 or more letters, you must specify that what comes next is whitespace or end-of-line (or whatever), as Anirvan does.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` and write a regex rule to match the lines you want to keep. You can get info on grep by typing `man grep` in the terminal.